# Will I receive any scrutiny from US border control if I have a Russian stamp on my passport?

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, russia

My friend is visiting Russia and invited me to go with them.

I hold a US B1/B2 visa and frequently travel to the US for business and for pleasure.

What are the chances that I will be questioned, denied entrance, etc in the US border if I have a Russian entry stamp on my passport?

Comment: what is your fear based on?

Comment: Is your stated purpose of visit "to interfere in US elections"?

Comment: @ThisIsMyName tensions between the two countries

Comment: The chance of being denied entrance solely because of a Russian stamp in your passport, or solely because you've been to Russia, is zero.  I have no idea about the chance that you'll be questioned about it, but it's probably only marginally higher than if you had a stamp for, say, France.  The Russian stamp, like any stamp, could lead to your being denied entry if it prompts a line of questioning that uncovers some ground of inadmissibility.

Comment: I think that this is opinion-based question. A lot of people has working visas and travel into both countries. I have L1 visa, and had no problems neother on Russia's borders nor on USA ones. I think it much more about your behavior.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The US border agents aren't likely to deny anyone solely for having a Russian stamp in their passport.

It may raise questions, like with any travel to any country of 'interest' or just out curiosity.  They may ask what the reason for travel there was, or who you interacted with.

However, if your reasons for travel are all legitimate, and you fulfill the conditions for entry into the US, you're unlikely to run into more than a couple of rudimentary questions.  I've technically visited Russia 3 times, and have been in the USA 5 times since, and had no questions. Not even questioned about my time in Cuba. My Colombia stamp caused me more questions, but even that was fine eventually.